# Heroku - Need to change the original 'seeded' user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a `Rails` application deployed to `Heroku`. The `db/seed` file has since change, and I would like the `admin` user that was originally seeded into `Heroku` to reflect the one I now have locally. Is there a way to either:

A) Destroy the data, and just run `heroku run rake db:seed` again?  or

B) Seed a new `admin` user into the database. Similar to creating a new migration file if I needed to edit the table in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, so many `code` `blocks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely reset your database using the `rake db:reset` command which will drop, create and seed your data. You would have to modify your seed file before running this command.

However, the better method would be to use `heroku run rails console` and simply modify the user information using that interface. You can read more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#console).